# VoicePHP record audio file

Tags: php

I'm using [VoicePHP](http://voicephp.com/).

I'm Brazilian and when I run the command `echo 'Ola mundo';` that is *Hello World* in my language. However using this software, the pronounciation isn't very good - can I do anything about that? Also, I'd like to know if I can record a message as MP3 or WMA, and run it.

I asked the support channel at the VoicePHP developers, Tringme, and they answered this:

> You can specify an audio file. Read more about it at http://voicephp.com/developers.html and also checkout http://code.voicephp.com.

But I didn't find anything specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method play($file), documented here:

http://voicephp.com/api/play.html